# Looping over parameters added by Jenkins extended choice parameters

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-groovy, extended-choice-parameter

I've added an extendedChoice param on my .groovy file as below

```
extendedChoice(name: 'Subscription', defaultValue: 'demo_standard', description: 'Check mark on subscription/Part number', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'demo_standard,demo_advanced,trial_standard,trial_advanced,standard,advanced', visibleItemCount: 6),
```

for calling this param I have below line.

```
sh "./create.js ${params.Username} ${params.Subscription} "
```

From the above line what I want to do is. If I select 2 | 3 | 4 | till 6 checks for subscriptions in params then above sh line should run those multiple times.

Example:

If I select  "demo_advanced,trial_standard" then it should call sh command twice with both subscriptions.

```
sh "./create.js ${params.Username} ${params.Subscription} -->(demo_advanced will replace)"
sh "./create.js ${params.Username} ${params.Subscription} -->(trial_standard will replace)"
```

How can I write this on my .groovy file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a full sample of how you can do this in your Pipeline.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        extendedChoice(name: 'Subscription', defaultValue: 'demo_standard', description: 'Check mark on subscription/Part number', multiSelectDelimiter: ',', quoteValue: false, saveJSONParameterToFile: false, type: 'PT_CHECKBOX', value: 'demo_standard,demo_advanced,trial_standard,trial_advanced,standard,advanced', visibleItemCount: 6)
    ])
])

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{
          script {
            echo "${params.Subscription}" 
            for(def sub : params.Subscription.split(',')) {
                sh "./create.js ${params.Username} ${sub}"
            }
          }
          
        }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m testing it. Will sub works to execute sh command multiple times with different selected subscriptions  if we select multiple subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, it will iterate over all selected subscriptions and execute multiple times.

Comment: Hey @ycr thanks and it worked as expected. This is really helpfull